# Bitmap Compressor() returns null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I'm using this method in a fragment to compress an image, if I'm not mistaken and then upload it to google firebase server:

```
Bitmap thumb_bitmap = new Compressor(this.getActivity())
                    .setMaxWidth(200)
                    .setMaxHeight(200)
                    .setQuality(75)
                    .compressToBitmap(thumb_filePath);
```

I end up getting the following error from Android Studio:

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference`

This is the rest of the code for the method:

```
private void uploadImage() {

        if (filePath[0] != null && filePath[1] != null) {

            final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            //progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading...");
            //progressDialog.show();

            for ( Uri path : filePath ) {

                id_or_proof += 1;

                File thumb_filePath = new File(path.getPath());

                Log.d ( "THUMB FILE PATH", path.getPath() );

                String current_user_id = mCurrentUser.getUid();

                Bitmap thumb_bitmap = new Compressor(this.getActivity())
                        .setMaxWidth(200)
                        .setMaxHeight(200)
                        .setQuality(75)
                        .compressToBitmap(thumb_filePath);

                Log.d (  "BITMAP", String.valueOf(thumb_bitmap));

                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                thumb_bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
                final byte[] thumb_byte = baos.toByteArray();

                StorageReference filepath = mImageStorage.child("profile_images").child(current_user_id + ".jpg");
                final StorageReference thumb_filepath = mImageStorage.child("profile_images").child("thumbs").child(current_user_id + ".jpg");


                filepath.putFile(path).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {

                        if(task.isSuccessful()){

                            final String download_url = task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString();

                            UploadTask uploadTask = thumb_filepath.putBytes(thumb_byte);
                            uploadTask.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> thumb_task) {

                                    String thumb_downloadUrl = thumb_task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString();

                                    if(thumb_task.isSuccessful()){

                                        if ( id_or_proof == 1 ) {
                                            Map update_hashMap = new HashMap();
                                            update_hashMap.put("id_image", download_url);
                                            update_hashMap.put("thumb_id_image", thumb_downloadUrl);

                                            mUserDatabase.updateChildren(update_hashMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                                        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                                                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Success Uploading.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                                    }

                                                }
                                            });
                                        }


                                        if ( id_or_proof == 2 ) {
                                            Map update_hashMap = new HashMap();
                                            update_hashMap.put("proof_image", download_url);
                                            update_hashMap.put("thumb_proof_image", thumb_downloadUrl);

                                            mUserDatabase.updateChildren(update_hashMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                                        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                                                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Success Uploading.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                                    }

                                                }
                                            });
                                        }

                                    } else {

                                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error in uploading thumbnail.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        mProgressDialog.dismiss();

                                    }


                                }
                            });



                        } else {

                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error in uploading.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            mProgressDialog.dismiss();

                        }

                    }
                });

            }// end of for

        }// end of if ()

    } // end of uploadImage()
```

I need help trying to figure out why I'm getting the error that I'm getting and also how I can fix it.

Much Appreciated.

Here's the logcat:

`03-14 15:36:57.383 2780-2780/in.tvac.akshaye.lapitchat E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /document/60 (No such file or directory)
        03-14 15:36:57.383 2780-2780/in.tvac.akshaye.lapitchat E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /document/60 (No such file or directory)
        03-14 15:36:57.383 2780-2780/in.tvac.akshaye.lapitchat D/BITMAP: null
        03-14 15:36:57.383 2780-2780/in.tvac.akshaye.lapitchat D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
        03-14 15:36:57.384 2780-2780/in.tvac.akshaye.lapitchat E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: in.tvac.akshaye.lapitchat, PID: 2780
        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference
        at in.tvac.akshaye.lapitchat.PersonalInforamtionFragment.uploadImage(PersonalInforamtionFragment.java:649)
        at in.tvac.akshaye.lapitchat.PersonalInforamtionFragment.access$1900(PersonalInforamtionFragment.java:57)
        at in.tvac.akshaye.lapitchat.PersonalInforamtionFragment$8.onComplete(PersonalInforamtionFragment.java:767)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzc$1.run(Unknown Source:23)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)`

Comment: check your thumb_filePath , if its null or not

Comment: it is not null.

It returns `/document/60`

Comment: Bitmap thumb_bitmap = new Compressor(this.getActivity()) , In this Use only getActivity()

Comment: I Have, still getting error. also used getActivity().getApplicationContext()

Comment: post full logcat here

Comment: Yes, have done that...

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are passing the wrong Uri to the new File, so it is not finding your file.

**Get from External Storage.**

If you are trying to get the file from the External Storage you have to add this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Then create the path like this:

```
String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/document/60";
Uri path = Uri.parse(filePath);
```

**Get from app storage**

If you are trying to get the file from App Storage, just build your Uri like this:

```
String filePath = getActivity().getFilesDir() + "/document/60";
Uri path = Uri.parse(filePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use correct context

```
Bitmap thumb_bitmap = new Compressor(this.getActivity())
                        .setMaxWidth(200)
                        .setMaxHeight(200)
                        .setQuality(75)
                        .compressToBitmap(thumb_filePath);
```

Replace it with this

```
Bitmap thumb_bitmap = new Compressor(getActivity())
                            .setMaxWidth(200)
                            .setMaxHeight(200)
                            .setQuality(75)
                            .compressToBitmap(thumb_filePath);
```

**Also the path should be correct as well**

Comment: It is not help :(

Comment: post full logcat

Comment: What you think is the difference between this.getActivity() and getActivity()?